# Convert array in Excel VBA to Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I had code in Excel VBA that I want to convert to run in Powerpoint VBA as well. here is what I have so far in ppt VBA:

```
Dim wbkISS As Excel.Workbook
Dim varSheetISS As Excel.Worksheet

Set wbkISS = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\...\Documents\ISS.xlsm")
Set varSheetISS = wbkISS.Worksheets("For ISS")

strIDRangeISS = "A2:D50"

varSheetISS = varSheetISS.Range(strIDRangeISS)

For iRowISS = LBound(varSheetISS, 1) To UBound(varSheetISS, 1)
    ...
    For iRowFCST = LBound(varSheetFCST, 1) To UBound(varSheetFCST, 1)
        ...
```

But at "LBound(varsheetISS" it gives me the Compile error: Expected Array. My code works fine in Excel so I'm thinking I have the wrong syntax for ppt?

Comment: This code suffers from no 'Option Explicit' Header.

Comment: That really works fine in Excel?  Pretty sure it does not...   If you want to run that in PPT you will first need to create an Excel Application object

Comment: Sorry the excel vba version is different, the code I posted there is what I modified so far for ppt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to post as answer:

This code suffers from no **'Option Explicit'** Header.

The variable `varSheetISS` is being passed around recklessly.

It start life life as a worksheet, then is cast to a range(where the intention was to get the Range's Value).

A lot of this can be avoided by using Option Explicit.

`Dim issArray As Variant: issArray = varSheetISS.Range(strIDRangeISS).Value2`